# Tableau - not showing SQL Server stored procedure with "User Defined Table Type"

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api

Using Tableau 2019.1.1. I'm attempting to create a data source tied to a SQL Server stored procedure. The stored procedure has an optional "User Defined Table Type" parameter.

In the Tableau development environment that stored procedure is not displayed.  However, when the optional "User Defined Table Type" parameter is removed from the stored procedure, it shows up in the Tableau development environment.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see stored procedures with non-scalar parameters (i.e. user defined table types) are not supported in Tableau